# Running out of Memory using for or foreach and a C++-function with Rcpp

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, rcpp

I want to generate a large Matrix (around 300.000 * 5000) and fill it with random samples from a given Vector of observations.

The R-Code Looks as follows:

```
library(foreach)
elements <- as.numeric(1:1000)

result_list <- foreach(i=(1:50)) %do% {
  mypackage::rddrawmatrixC2(n_bootstrap = 100, 
                             n_obs_censusdata = 300000,
                             elements_to_draw_from = elements))))
}
```

rddrawmatrixC2 is a C++ - function exported with Rcpp. I wrote it, since sample() seemed to be much slower.

As I am optimising for speed I tried different approaches:

- using foreach. Both sequentially and parallelized.
- using a simple for loop on a previously initialized list `result_list <- vetor("list", 50)`
- using a data.table and adding columns instead of rows with `:=` or `set()`
- writing the results in temporary files works, but is painfully slow.

Every Approach resulted in an error

> cannot allocate Vector of n mb

with n variying between 1.6 mb and 200 mb.

I suppose it has nothing to do with my function, as the same Thing happens in this simple example, where the first line works fine, but the loop doesn't:

```
m <- matrix(1:6000*5000, nrow = 6000, ncol = 5000)
result_list <- foreach(i=(1:50)) %do% {
  matrix(1:6000*5000, nrow = 6000, ncol = 5000)
}
```

As far as I know altering items of a list should not result in the entire list being copied internally and the := Operator in data.table should definitely avoid unnecessary Information being accessed. Do you have any explanations / workaraounds? Might that be in an issue that has to do with Rcpp? Is there a way to create the entire list with Rcpp to avoid the Problem and to then return the list without crashing R's Memory again?

I am working on Windows 10, R 3.4.4. If other information is needed I will be happy to supply it.

Any help (and also feedback to my code) is much appreciated, thank you!

This is the code for the C++ - function:

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <random>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP rddrawmatrixC2(const int n_bootstrap,
                    const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> elements_to_draw_from, 
                    const int n_obs_censusdata)
{
  const int upper = elements_to_draw_from.size();
  std::random_device rd; // used to obtain a seed for the number engine
  std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // Mersenne Twister engine 
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, upper);

  // initialise matrix that can be filled
  NumericMatrix returnmatrix(n_obs_censusdata, n_bootstrap);
  const int matrixsize = n_obs_censusdata * n_bootstrap;

  for (int i=0; i<matrixsize; ++i)
    returnmatrix[i] = elements_to_draw_from[dis(gen)-1]; // subtract 1 because in C++ indices start with 0

  return Rcpp::wrap(returnmatrix);
}
```

(there also is a Version of this function that doesn't use Rcpp::Eigen, but the error is the same)

Edit / Addendum: 
The Problem apparently lies not in the use of for/foreach/Rcpp. Rather it seems to be that even though only small parts are accessed at a time, R still has to keep the entire list / data.table in memory. One solution is to write data into files or use File Based Matrices as provided in the package bigstatsr.

As Ralf Stubner and Florian Privé pointed out, good places to start are: 
https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/#filling-something-in-parallel https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr

Comment: 300k * 5k * 8 bytes gives 1.2e10 bytes or 12gb. Do you have that?  To a first approximation, R always wants three times as much RAM as your largest element, hence 36 gb.  In short: maybe look into _sparse_ matrices instead.  We have support for those.

Comment: And if you do not have enough memory: Have a look at packages like https://cran.r-project.org/package=bigmemory or https://cran.r-project.org/package=bigstatsr.

Comment: As @RalfStubner pointed out (thanks BTW!), it would be convenient to use package {bigstatsr} (disclaimer: I'm the author) to solve your problem. For your specific problem, have a look at https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/#filling-something-in-parallel. For more info on the package, have a look at https://github.com/privefl/bigstatsr. If it is not clear enough, please ask some questions and I will give you the answer.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel ah yes that was maybe not precise enough: I don't necessarily need one matrix or data.table as a whole, I merely need the 300k time 5k entries, and need to be able to work with them (simple addition and matrix multiplication). As I don't have 12gb my idea was to work with a list of smaller matrices, never accessing more than one item at time. Is that doomed to fail in principle?

Comment: Unfortunately  the matrix is not sparse, but I will have a look into the other packages. Also thank you very much for your help and your quick replies!

Comment: Bigstatsr seems really amazing. I am still curious as to why simply accessing single smaller list items does not work...

Comment: Even if you access only one of the smaller matrices at a time, R still has to keep the entire list in memory. That’s why the packages I mentioned can help. Feel free to answer the question yourself if one of them works for you.

Comment: @F.Privé: would I then simply replace a subset of the FBM with a numeric Matrix, or can I alter the FBM within my C++ - Function, e.g. BMAcc<double> macc = Matrix within Rcpp?

Comment: You have similar accessors as R and Rcpp matrices. Please see https://privefl.github.io/R-presentation/bigstatsr.html. You can e.g. do `X[, 1:10] <- mat`.

Comment: This I understood, and I also saw your example on slide 28 where you access the FBM through x[j] macc(i, j). But is that read only access or can I also alter the content from within Rcpp, e.g. macc(i, j) = x[j]? When I tried this the R session aborted, but it might also be due to a different error I overlooked.

Comment: Yes you can. My guess for your session crash is that you didn't use the right `MatrixAccessor` type? Also, don't use `int` type for `matrixsize = n_obs_censusdata * n_bootstrap`, use `std::size_t`, otherwise you'll likely suffer from integer overflow.

Comment: I tried the following: `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]] 
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH, bigstatsr, RcppEigen)]] 
#include <RcppEigen.h> 
#include <bigstatsr/BMAcc.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> X, 
          Environment fbm)
{
  XPtr<FBM> xpMat = fbm["address"];
  BMAcc<double> macc(xpMat);
  macc(1,5) = X(5,2);
}

A <- bigstatsr::FBM(5,5)
X <- matrix(1,5,5)
X[5,2] <- 2

test(X = X, fbm = A)
` however FBM A was left unchanged. What am I missing? Thank you very much :) (sorry for the formatting, how can I add <br/> in comments?

Comment: In C++, indices starts at 0. So, when you're using 5, your basically writting outside of the matrix, somewhere in memory. If this memory is occupied by something else, this will make your session crash.

Comment: that was a very stupid mistake. Now it works, thank you! Is there also a way to access the matrix as a whole (I know you normally wouldn't do that)? macc() = X did not work (it said something like '=' cannot be overloaded.

Comment: In C++, you can only access one element by one element. In R, you can use `[]` or `[,]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reprex

```
elements <- as.numeric(1:1000)

my_fun <- function(n_bootstrap,
                   n_obs_censusdata,
                   elements_to_draw_from) {
  replicate(n_bootstrap, sample(elements_to_draw_from, n_obs_censusdata, TRUE))
}
```

#### Foreach solution with FBM

```
library(bigstatsr)
X <- FBM(300000, 5000)

library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeCluster(nb_cores()))
foreach(i = 1:50, .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
  cols <- 1:100 + (i - 1) * 100
  X[, cols] <- my_fun(n_bootstrap = 100,
                      n_obs_censusdata = 300000,
                      elements_to_draw_from = elements)
  NULL
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Note that `foreach` returns something, this is why I use `NULL` because we only want to assign here.

#### Directly with big_apply

`big_apply` takes care of the splitting / parallelism for you.

```
big_apply(X, a.FUN = function(X, ind, my_fun, elements) {
  X[, ind] <- my_fun(n_bootstrap = length(ind),
                     n_obs_censusdata = 300000,
                     elements_to_draw_from = elements)
  NULL
}, a.combine = 'c', ncores = nb_cores(), block.size = 100,
my_fun = my_fun, elements = elements)
```

Comment: Ah perfect. This is about what I had derived myself from your resources, but your subsetting is far more elegant. Is there an intuition as to which way is faster (foreach or big_apply) and what block.size or respectively what combination of i and n_boot would be optimal? Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: The two are equivalent, `big_apply` just wraps `foreach` for you.
Here, I used `block.size = 100` to reproduce what you had. Normally, if dividing columns, you could leave this and the default will cut blocks of no more than 1GB.